# Angular 2 Select - set default value in select

Tags: angular, html-select

I currently have this code which loops through and array making each `optgroup`, then loops through nested arrays, making each `option` and account type.  I am trying to set the default value of the select to the first account type of the first nested array with this code:

```
<select class="q-select"
        ngModel
        name="answerForQuestion{{ question?.questionId }}">
    <optgroup label="{{subCat?.subCat}}"
        *ngFor="let subCat of accountTypes; let i = index;">
        <option *ngFor="let acctType of subCat.accountTypes; let j = index;"
                [ngValue]="acctType"
                [selected]="i == 0 && j == 0">
                    {{ acctType?.displayName }}
        </option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I am using `[selected]="i == 0 && j == 0"` to set the default selected to the first account type in the first nested array but for some reason this is not working.

I appreciate any help on how to fix this.

Also, I do not want to use two way binding with [(ngModel)].

Thanks

Comment: *I do not want to use two way binding with [(ngModel)]*: why? How will you know which answer is selected?

Comment: @JBNizet Because the select is part of a form and it has a control on it because I have `ngModel` on the `select`.  Everything in the form (and the form itself - this is one of many) is dynamic so I don't want to hard code any properties in my component ts file.  I feel like this code should work but I am not sure why it is not

Comment: As far as I know `selected` doesn't work with `ngModel` and `ngValue`.

Comment: [(ngModel)]="currentItem" works for me on the select-tag!